# Angular http post data object isn't being seen as an object by the node server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using angular on the client side to perform a post to the server with a user object. This user object just lets me pass all the user information, username, password, email, name, etc. in one object. Instead of having to pass each one as a separate variable.

I see the following POST parameters in chrome's developer tools.

```
{"username":"adfasdfasdf","password":"12123123123"}
```

However, in my server side js the data is coming over as separate variables. Instead of an object with both the username and password. So, the console.log('userData = ' + userData) line logs the username. And the "done" variable contains the password.

Why am I not getting the object on the server side?

**CLIENT HTML**

```
<form class="form-signin", ng-submit="register()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
</form>
```

**CLIENT JS**

```
    var pollControllers = angular.module('pollControllers', []);
pollControllers.controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
            // This object is filled by the form
            $scope.user = {};

            $scope.register = function() {
                $http.post('http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:3000/register', $scope.user);
            }
    }
]);
```

**SERVER JS**

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
  function(userData, done) {
    console.log('userData = ' + userData); // !this outputs the username!
    console.log('done = ' + done); // !this outputs the password!
  }
}
```

Comment: i'd have a look at the passport code - in my experience it is fiddly to set up correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport local gets 1st params as username, 2nd param as password and 3rd as callback.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

[Passport Local Github Page](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/)

Comment: Okay so passport expects those parameters for this strategy. That is what I was initially doing. But I want to pass additional info that the user has entered like email, first name, last name, etc. Which is why I was trying to pass an object. So I didn't have to make a new argument for each additional field.